Why the component's state is not updating?
I would like to add the the .selected class whenever the activeItem matches with the index of the <li> element but the state is not updating even though console.log(index) is showing the actual value of the selected index but in the callback function console.log(this.state.activeItem) is not showing anything, not even undefined or 0. What is it neccesary to be done to uptade the state and re render the component? Here is my component's class:
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './MobileNavigation.module.css'
import home from '../../assets/images/home-white.png'
import about from '../../assets/images/about-white.png'
import patients from '../../assets/images/patients-white.png'
import team from '../../assets/images/team-white.png'
import services from '../../assets/images/services-white.png'
import contact from '../../assets/images/contact-white.png'

class MobileNavigationComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    activeItem: 0
  };

  selectOption = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
    this.setState({
      activeItem: index
    }, ()=>{
      console.log(this.state.activeItem)
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles.MobileMenuModal}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>Menu</h1>
        <ul className={styles.mobileMenu}>
          {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              onClick={() => {
                this.selectOption(index);
                this.props.toggleMenu();
              }}
              className={index === activeItem ? styles.selected : ''}
            >
              <img src={item.icon} alt={item.label} />
              <Link to={item.path}>{item.label}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const menuItems = [
  { icon: home, path: '/', label: 'Inicio' },
  { icon: about, path: '/about', label: 'Acerca de' },
  { icon: patients, path: '/patients', label: 'Nuevos pacientes' },
  { icon: team, path: '/team', label: 'Equipo' },
  { icon: services, path: '/services', label: 'Servicios' },
  { icon: contact, path: '/contact', label: 'Contacto' }
];
export default MobileNavigationComponent;

I've already destructure the state of the component within the render method as you can see but still it doesn't work.

try to initialise the state in the constructor it should work fine, suggest to use the functional components
